# How to use a class a file in the root folder using a class in another namespce?

Tags: php

I have some code in a `test.php` file that is on the root folder for testing some email sending.

I have this on the top of the `test.php` file to use the `SendEmail` class on this file:

```
use midd\App\Helpers\SendEmail;
```

Because is necessary to use the SendEmail as below:

```
$data= [
    'from' => $receiver,
    'to' => $sender,

];

SendEmail::Init($data)->send();
```

But I'm getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "App\Helpers\SendEmail" not
> found in /projects/project/www/test.php:15

The `SendEmail` class is in `middleware/app/Helpers`.

Do you know what is necessary to use the `SendEmail` class on the `test.php` file?

Comment: You tagged this with nothing but `php`, so we don't know if you are using any framework there, that provides autoloader functionality for classes ...? Please add proper details to your question.

Comment: How does that file look like? Does it contain a proper autoloader? Also, why did you import `midd\App\Helpers\SendEmail` when the name of the class is different?

Comment: A [`use` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) only imports the [namespace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) into the current context. It doesn't physically add the PHP file into the main script. For that you need to use `require` or `include` - unless you have an autoloader. It's not clear what, if anything, you've done to actually import the file itself, or whether the SendEmail class is in the namespace quoted by your `use` statement. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. See also [ask]